Not Receiving Callbacks for Security Logs in DeviceAdminReceiver
I'm developing an app that acts as a Device Policy Controller on Android, primarily focusing on enabling and handling security logging. Despite following the documentation to set up everything correctly and enabling security logging, I'm not receiving the onSecurityLogsAvailable callbacks in my DeviceAdminReceiver subclass, although I am able to receive network logs through a different mechanism.
My app is confirmed to be the device owner via ADB.
Below is the simplified code related to enabling logging and setting up the DeviceAdminReceiver.
...
 DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
ComponentName adminComponentName = new ComponentName(context, AppDeviceAdminReceiver.class);

if (dpm.isDeviceOwnerApp(context.getPackageName())) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        dpm.setAffiliationIds(adminComponentName, Collections.singleton("my.unique.id"));
        dpm.setSecurityLoggingEnabled(adminComponentName, true);
        dpm.setNetworkLoggingEnabled(adminComponentName, true);
        Log.d("Setup", "Logging enabled");
        return true;
    }
} else {
    Log.w("Setup", "Not device owner, cannot enable logging.");
    return false;
}
...

AppDeviceAdminReceiver implementation:
public class AppDeviceAdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
    
    @Override
    public void onSecurityLogsAvailable(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent) {
        Log.i("AdminReceiver", "Security logs available.");
        // TODO: Handle logs...
    }

    @Override
    public void onNetworkLogsAvailable(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent, long batchToken, int networkLogsCount) {
        Log.i("AdminReceiver", "Network logs available, count: " + networkLogsCount);
        // TODO: Handle logs...
    }
}


AppDeviceAdminReceiver in the Manifest.xml:
        <receiver
            android:name=".AppDeviceAdminReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN"
            android:exported="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

I attempted unlocking the device with the wrong code 5 times, enabling and disabling Bluetooth and Wifi and installing / uninstalling an app using adb and also forced security logs generation using the command adb -s device_name shell dpm force-security-logs. Despite this, I still did not receive any security log callbacks.
On the other hand, I am able to receive network logs, but only when I utilize the onReceive method like so in AppDeviceAdminReceiver, and not via the recommended onNetworkLogsAvailable callback:
@Override
public void onReceive(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent) {
    Log.i("AppDeviceAdminReceiver", "Received intent: " + intent.getAction());
}

(I could live with that, it's just another issue I am having that may be related).
I tested this behavior across multiple devices from different vendors, ranging from Android 10 to 14, with no success in receiving security logs.
I'm wondering if there might be additional configurations or permissions that I've overlooked for the reception of this callback. Any insights or suggestions on why this  might not be work would be greatly appreciated.
